# What is the proper way to transmit text through WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, text, websocket

I'm developing a Web application using WebSockets, so at some point I need to send a text file to the web browser (chrome in this case), but chrome just calls onerror without giving me any clue about what's wrong. If I work with FireFox, it just says there was an error, but again, it gives me no real clue.

At first I though I was doing something wrong on the server side, until I thought: What if I tweek the opcode and tell the socket I'm sending binary data, so I did, and as I imagined no error occurred, chrome got the file and everything was fine, except that there's no way I know to convert binary data into text using JavaScript. That lead me to write a function to encode the text in such a way that the encoded version contains no special characters, again, no error... so this is obviously a problem of the text itself.

Currenlty the only way I've being able to work around is by encoding and decoding the text, however I'm not quite sure this is the right way to do it. So I wish to know: is there better way?

Comment: Solved!, I read again the rfc6455 and realized I needed to UTF-8 encode the text before sending it to the client. Hope this may help someone else.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question with solution and your valuable findings so that other can be helped ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to decode the frame in Browser. It's already decoding the binary message (standard websocket format).

I have just committed a working minimal websocket server to github. You can give a try.
[SGwebsocket](https://github.com/selcukgun/SGwebsocket.git)

If you want to implement by yourself you will need  [RFC6455 reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for decoding and encoding the frames.